# Add subdirectory to url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add a subdirectory to my URL. So for example, my /news must go to /blog/news including all their articles

I came up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/news/$1 [R,L]
```

See below for fix!

Comment: and what happened when you ran the above code? Because that _should_ work.

Comment: I'ts actually giving me an error, because it's redirecting everything to /blog/news. EDIT: it seems it doesn't take the /news/ into consideration. So it redirects the url even when it not has /news in it

Comment: Hey Huub, glad you fixed it. Could you please post your fix as answer. Easier for people that have a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry, I just did. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Awesome, made a slight edit (not to the code). Accept your answer :)

Comment: Thanks for making the answer appropriate. I can only accept my own answer in 2 days, which I will do when i can, thanks again man!

Comment: Well, it's not working after all. After I used this code on my live website, it doesn't get used at all.

Comment: Does the `/blog/` directory actually exist? Because your answer below is a redirect, not a rewrite. So if the directory does not exist, it will not work.

Comment: I wanted to test it first without actually making the changes, so no the new url does not exist yet, which could explain why it's not working. Although I find it strange that it doesn't actually rewrite the url, because that is what it supposed to do right?

Comment: Ok, I'm confusing the rewrite with a redirect. I want the user to see that the URL changes to something new. It doesn't have to be stealthed..

Comment: Yes, the issue with your answer below is that it is redirecting to the `blog` directory. You would need to actually have a directory with that name for it to work. That explains why it is now not working since you've taken it live.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /blog/news/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Make sure to clear your cache when testing and to set `R=302` as that will make it a temporary redirect. Set it back to `R=301` once you know it is working.

Comment: Not working after all unfortunately. It seems that this rule is ignored and not used on my live site.